# Mindmeld Elasticsearch index and QuestionAnswerer

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, mindmeld

I am using Mindmeld blueprint application (kwik_e_mart) to understand how the Question Answerer retrieves data from relevant knowledge base data file (newbie to Mindmeld, OOP and Elasticsearch).
See code snippet below:

```
from mindmeld.components import QuestionAnswerer
config = {"model_type": "keyword"}
qa = QuestionAnswerer(app_path='kwik_e_mart', config=config)
qa.load_kb(app_namespace='kwik_e_mart', index_name='stores', 
data_file='kwik_e_mart/data/stores.json', app_path='kwik_e_mart', config=config, clean = True)


Output - Loading Elasticsearch index stores: 100%|██████████| 25/25 [00:00<00:00, 495.28it/s]
Output -Loaded 25 documents
```

Although Elasticsearch is able to load all 25 documents (see output above), unable to retrieve any data with index greater than 9.

```
stores = qa.get(index='stores')
stores[0]


Output: - {'address': '23 Elm Street, Suite 800, Springfield, OR, 97077',
           'store_name': '23 Elm Street',
           'open_time': '7:00',
           'location': {'lon': -123.022029, 'lat': 44.046236},
           'phone_number': '541-555-1100',
           'id': '1',
           'close_time': '19:00',
           '_score': 1.0}
```

However, stores [10] gives an error

```
  `stores[10]`

   Output: - IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-12-08132a2cd460> in <module>
   ----> 1 stores[10]

   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Not sure why documents at index higher than 9 are unreachable. My understanding is that the elasticsearch index is still pointing to remote blueprint data (http/middmeld/blueprint...) and not pointing to the folder locally.

Not sure how to resolve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `get()` method only returns 10 records per search - so only `stores[0]` through `stores[9]` will be valid.

You can add the `size=` option to your `get()` to increase the number of records it returns:

```
stores = qa.get(index='stores', size=25)
```

See [the bottom of this section](https://www.mindmeld.com/docs/userguide/kb.html#perform-simple-searches-with-the-get-api) for more info.